# How can I find an element by passing in a variable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I tried the following and it works:

```
$('#row_').remove();
```

However now I would like to make it depend on the value of a variable. For example if the number of the row is contained in the variable id:

```
var id = 4;
$('#row_').remove();
```

How can I make it so the above looks for row 4 by using the id variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
var id = 4;
$("#row_"+id).remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are given `id` to your rows at the time of creation, then you can use like this:

```
var id = 4; $('#row_'+id).remove();
```

Otherwise you can make things work like below: (this wont require to give ID to each row

```
var id = 4;
$('table tr :nth-child('+ id +')').remove();
```

Comment: Your second suggestion will only work for child of `tr` elements. I think OP is asking for any element.

Comment: @Ajinkya ~ Sangeeta's second answer assumes that the IDs are generated sequentially; it wouldn't be much of a problem to change the `table tr` part of his solution to something else, and given sequential elements, `:nth-child()` is most probably the correct way to deal with this problem. Numbering sequential elements for the sake of targeting doesn't sound like good design.

Comment: @Richard: Yes completely agree. Just wanted it to bring it to notice. +1 for suggesting `:nth-child()`.

Comment: @Richard: hey can u tell y is it not good design to number sequential elements for the sake of targeting?

Comment: @Sangeeta ~ well, for one, you'd be generating unnecessary markup, which makes for a heavier bandwidth payload. Why mark a row as `id="row_24"` when you can target it via `tr:eq(23)`? (I mean, besides the obvious CSS requirement, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Just append number to `id` field and Try

```
var id = 4;
$('#row_'+id).remove();
```